# Control activates before button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, jquery-events

I have a custom toolbar that fires events on html button click, there is a problem with one where it's activated on init instead of after button click.. it seems to trigger the function on init.
The controls toggle correctly but it seems to be activated by default or within init.

Here is the code:

```
/* other Controls */   
    polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(
        OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon, {
            persist: true,
            immediate: true,
            handlerOptions: {
                layerOptions: {
                    renderers: renderer,
                    styleMap: styleMap
                }
            }
        }   
    ),
    choose: new OpenLayers.Control.Button({ /** **/
        activateControl: false,             /** Problem here **/
        trigger: tochiSentaku()             /** **/
    })
};

var control;
for(var key in allControls) {
    control = allControls[key];
    control.events.on({
        "measure": handleMeasurements,
        "measurepartial": handleMeasurements,
        "button": tochiSentaku
    });
    map.addControl(control);
}

function toggleControl(element){
    for(key in allControls){
        var control = allControls[key];
        if(control.active){
            control.deactivate();
        }
        if(element.value == key && element.click){
            control.activate();
            vlayer.removeAllFeatures();
            var mybutton = document.getElementById('output');
            var xyz = "";
            mybutton.innerHTML = xyz;
        }
        else{
            control.deactivate();
        }
        
    }
}
```

`tochiSentaku` Function

```
function tochiSentaku(evt){
    var element = document.getElementById("attribute");
    map.events.register('click', map, function(e){
        vlayer.destroyFeatures(vlayer,features);
        var coord = $(".olControlMousePosition").text();
        
        $("#attribute").html('<center><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Now Loading..." /></center>');
        $.getJSON("scripts/tochi_sentaku.php",{coord:coord}, function(data){
            $("#attribute").html("<button id=\"attribute_map\" onclick=\"" + data.the_geom + "\">地図</button><table id='attribute_tbl'><tr><th>項目名</th><th>値</th></tr></table>");
            for(var key in data){
                if(key != "the_geom"){
                $("#attribute_tbl").append("<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + data[key] + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
            $("#attribute_map").click();
        });
    });
}
```

If anyone can give me some advice would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of using

```
trigger:tochiSentaku
```

I used

```
activate:tochiSentaku
```

@simplyharsh Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the definition of `tochiSentaku` in your code snippet.

But my initial guess would be, to change the code to

```
choose: new OpenLayers.Control.Button({
    activateControl: false,
    trigger: tochiSentaku
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried and while it does stop the even from firing within init. It stops the event altogether. Have just added the tochiSentaku() function to my Question